# Adding an ElasticSearch connection to app.module on Nestjs

Tags: elasticsearch, module, dependencies, nestjs, nestjs-config

I'm trying to create a connection with [ElasticSearch](https://github.com/nestjs/elasticsearch) on my app.module.ts.
My project folder looks like:

```
src
 |database
   |- elasticsearch-database.module.ts
   |- es.services.ts
 |services
   |- products
      |-products.controller.ts
      |-products.module.ts
      |-products.service.ts
 app.module.ts
```

First, I'm creating the connection on `elasticsearch-database.module.ts`

```
 @Global()
    @Module({
        imports: [
            ElasticsearchModule.registerAsync({
                useFactory: () => ({
                  node: 'http://localhost:9200'
                })
              })
        ],
        providers: [SearchService],
        exports: [SearchService]
    })

export class elasticSearchDatabaseModule{}
```

My **SearchService** is on `es.services.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
  constructor(private readonly elasticsearchService: ElasticsearchService) {}
}
```

Then, I'm importing **elasticSearchDatabaseModule** on

```
app.module.ts

@Module({
  imports: [
    elasticSearchDatabaseModule,
    ProductsModule
  ],
  
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My **ProductsModule** on `products.module.ts`

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        elasticSearchDatabaseModule,

    ],
    controllers: [ProductsController],
    providers: [ ProductsService],
})

export class EventsModule { }
```

And finally, on **ProductsService** , I have

```
import { ElasticsearchService } from "@nestjs/elasticsearch";
@Injectable()
export class EventsService {
    constructor(
        private readonly elasticSearch      : ElasticsearchService
    ) { }
}
```

The error occuring is:

```
Potential solutions:
- If ElasticsearchService is a provider, is it part of the current EventsModule?
- If ElasticsearchService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within EventsModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ElasticsearchService */ ]
  })
 +3ms
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the EventsService (?). Please make sure that the argument ElasticsearchService at index [0] is available in the EventsModule context.
```

I am able to fully compile without error if I create the connection directly on `products.module.ts`:

```
imports: [
     
        ElasticsearchModule.register({
            node: 'http://elasticsearch:9200',
        })
    ]
```

But I think it's not the best approach if I want to use that elasticSearch connection in other services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to expose all the providers exported by that dynamic module (`ElasticsearchModule.registerAsync()` one), you'll need to export `ElasticsearchModule` module. See: https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#module-re-exporting

To do so, just add `ElasticsearchModule` to the `exports` array of `elasticSearchDatabaseModule` module.

Comment: That worked perfectly, I thought that simply importing elasticSearchDatabaseModule would do the trick, thanks!

Comment: you can think like this: the "public API" of a nestjs module is defined by the `exports` array. Thus, the `elasticSearchDatabaseModule` that you've have before was just exposing the provider `SearchService`